# SSRS 2008 add columns dynamically per id in a table.

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, grouping

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
ID  Name    Date
DCMTest1    Planning    02-06-12
DCMTest1    Planning    01-09-13
DCMTest1    Planning    06-09-13
DCMTest2    Planning    03-08-11
DCMTest2    Planning    05-07-12
```

The result table has to add columns dynamically (the amount of columns is unknown). Here is an example of how I want the data in the report:

```
ID          Planning    Planning    Planning
DCMTest1    02-06-12    01-09-13    06-09-13
DCMTest2    03-08-11    05-07-12
```

I have a row group on the ID (Project_nummer) and I have tried to get the result I want in two different ways.
I have used a column group header on the Date, which results in a column grouping per different date (which is obviously wrong):

Result1:

```
ID          Planning    Planning    Planning    Planning    Planning
DCMTest1    02-06-12    01-09-13    06-09-13        
DCMTest2                                        03-08-11    05-07-12
```

And I have tried a column group on the Name (planning) which gives result 2:

Result2:

```
ID          Planning
DCMTest1    02-06-12
DCMTest2    03-08-11
```

Result 2 has a correct start, but does not add columns dynamically. Do I miss an expression?

I am not yet allowed to upload pictures, so here is a link to the SSRS grouping: 
[SSRS grouping](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5I2P)

Any help is appreciated. I am working with MS SQL server 2008 and visual studio 9.0

Comment: Could you use it if it listed those dates in groups going down instead of across?

Comment: I personally prefer row groups as well, but this customer does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to mind for me is to alter your query a little bit to include row numbers partitioned by ID, then column group on the row numbers. Add a statement to your select clause in your query like this:

```
Row_Number() OVER (Order by ID) as Col_group,
```

That will give you a result set like this:

```
    ID   Col_group     Name       Date
DCMTest1    1       Planning    02-06-12
DCMTest1    2       Planning    01-09-13
DCMTest1    3       Planning    06-09-13
DCMTest2    1       Planning    03-08-11
DCMTest2    2       Planning    05-07-12
```

Then create a column group like you did in your Result 1, but use the new Col_group column to group on instead of date.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. This might work, with the exact dataset I have showed above. But there are more date columns with different dates and then the Col_group multiplies and shows all the possibilities. As example: one of the test projects has 8 rows, when I add the col_group it results in 65000 rows. Though I like the idea and I will keep on playing with it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: With some tweaks in my data & stored procedure and a partition by clause in the row_number I have been able to solve this problem. I still have to fix some other issues, but this question has been answered. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

if you want the data to use it in reporting services, the first dataset is OK, you just need to group the information in SSRS with a Matrix.

Comment: What would his column group be for the Matrix? Or, more generally, can you describe how you would set up the Matrix?

Comment: Could you please clarify this? I have modified the table with a row group and column group (which looks the same as a matrix). Now I have tried the matrix, but I don't see a difference. If I try result 1 I still get a column for every unique date and when I try result 2 I still only get one column.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer is useful.  He's clearly already using groups.